# Is there a way to use Cells.Address as part of a range ("A1:Cells.Address") for an input to a function?

Tags: excel, vba, automation, outlook

I cannot seem to make this work. I have a line that finds the address of the last cell in the table of data.

```
r = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count 
Range("A1", Cells(r + 1, 5).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)).Select
```

Then using this information, later on I need to input the range A1:E35 where the E35 corresponds to:

```
Cells(r + 1, 5).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False))
```

Using Ron de Bruin's CopyRangeToJPG function,

```
Function CopyRangeToJPG(NameWorksheet As String, RangeAddress As String) As String
'Ron de Bruin, 25-10-2019
Dim PictureRange As Range

With ActiveWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Activate
    Set PictureRange = .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Range(RangeAddress)
    
    If PictureRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sorry this is not a correct range"
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Function
    End If
```

It doesn't get past the validation check. What should the RangeAddress field be? I need this to be dynamic since it won't always be A1:E35 in this case. I would have thought that the following might have worked but I guess this isn't the right way.

```
CopyRangeToJPG("Sheet2", "A1:(Cells(r + 1, 5).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False))").
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
CopyRangeToJPG("Sheet2", _
               "A1:" & Cells(r + 1, 5).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False))
```